# JavaScript Audio Input

Tags: javascript, audio, input, microphone

I am Vanessa and I am working with a Team on a project for university. We are working with JavaScript and we try to measure a huge micro deflection. 
Our goal is to push off particles from the center of the canvas when hands are clapped. We just want to know how to convert the micro deflection to a number.

Thank´s a lot!
Vanessa

Comment: Please provide an example micro deflection

Comment: just like this one https://www.openprocessing.org/sketch/175689

Comment: If you want help- provide the actual data format. I'm not your research assistant.

Answer (score 0):

here is come code I wrote using Web Audio API which listens to the microphone and makes available both the time domain as well as frequency domain representation of the mic audio curve

```
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>capture microphone then show time & frequency domain output</title>

<script type="text/javascript">

var webaudio_tooling_obj = function () {

    var audioContext = new AudioContext();

    console.log("audio is starting up ...");

    var BUFF_SIZE_RENDERER = 16384;

    var audioInput = null,
    microphone_stream = null,
    gain_node = null,
    script_processor_node = null,
    script_processor_analysis_node = null,
    analyser_node = null;

    if (!navigator.getUserMedia)
        navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
    navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia;

    if (navigator.getUserMedia){

        navigator.getUserMedia({audio:true}, 
            function(stream) {
                start_microphone(stream);
            },
            function(e) {
                alert('Error capturing audio.');
            }
            );

    } else { alert('getUserMedia not supported in this browser.'); }

    // ---

    function show_some_data(given_typed_array, num_row_to_display, label) {

        var size_buffer = given_typed_array.length;
        var index = 0;

        console.log("__________ " + label);

        if (label === "time") {

            for (; index < num_row_to_display && index < size_buffer; index += 1) {

                var curr_value_time = (given_typed_array[index] / 128) - 1.0;

                console.log(curr_value_time);
            }

        } else if (label === "frequency") {

            for (; index < num_row_to_display && index < size_buffer; index += 1) {

                console.log(given_typed_array[index]);
            }

        } else {

            throw new Error("ERROR - must pass time or frequency");
        }
    }

    function process_microphone_buffer(event) {

        var i, N, inp, microphone_output_buffer;

        microphone_output_buffer = event.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0); // just mono - 1 channel for now
    }

    function start_microphone(stream){

        gain_node = audioContext.createGain();
        gain_node.connect( audioContext.destination );

        microphone_stream = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
        microphone_stream.connect(gain_node); 

        script_processor_node = audioContext.createScriptProcessor(BUFF_SIZE_RENDERER, 1, 1);
        script_processor_node.onaudioprocess = process_microphone_buffer;

        microphone_stream.connect(script_processor_node);

        // --- enable volume control for output speakers

        document.getElementById('volume').addEventListener('change', function() {

            var curr_volume = this.value;
            gain_node.gain.value = curr_volume;

            console.log("curr_volume ", curr_volume);
        });

        // --- setup FFT

        script_processor_analysis_node = audioContext.createScriptProcessor(2048, 1, 1);
        script_processor_analysis_node.connect(gain_node);

        analyser_node = audioContext.createAnalyser();
        analyser_node.smoothingTimeConstant = 0;
        analyser_node.fftSize = 2048;

        microphone_stream.connect(analyser_node);

        analyser_node.connect(script_processor_analysis_node);

        var buffer_length = analyser_node.frequencyBinCount;

        var array_freq_domain = new Uint8Array(buffer_length);
        var array_time_domain = new Uint8Array(buffer_length);

        console.log("buffer_length " + buffer_length);

        script_processor_analysis_node.onaudioprocess = function() {

            // get the average for the first channel
            analyser_node.getByteFrequencyData(array_freq_domain);
            analyser_node.getByteTimeDomainData(array_time_domain);

            // draw the spectrogram
            if (microphone_stream.playbackState == microphone_stream.PLAYING_STATE) {

                show_some_data(array_freq_domain, 5, "frequency");
                show_some_data(array_time_domain, 5, "time"); // store this to record to aggregate buffer/file
            }
        };
    }

}(); //  webaudio_tooling_obj = function()

</script>

</head>
<body>

    <p>Volume</p>
    <input id="volume" type="range" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" value="0.5"/>

</body>
</html>
```

just save this file and paste its file location into the browser ... you will get a prompt to acknowledge use of microphone ... to access audio data just see where I print snippets of it to javascript console ... so next step would be to write code to view the audio curve and take actions to move canvas objects